# Spring entitymanager

Tags: spring, entitymanager

I'm facing a problem with my application. My application reads messages from queues and persists to database. The insertion of the record is good. But when comes to update, it is missing randomly.  updated properly but 10% of the records are not getting updated randomly. Most of the records are getting below is the snippet of the code I am using:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public int updateTransaction(AuditRequest auditRequest) throws TesException {

        LOG.info("updateTransaction : Updating Event Transaction");
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("updateEventTransactionQuery");
        query.setParameter("status", auditRequest.getStatus());
        query.setParameter("failureInfo", auditRequest.getFailureInfo());
        query.setParameter("endDateTimestamp", getTimestamp(auditRequest.getEndDateTime()));
        query.setParameter("transUID", auditRequest.getTransUID());
        query.setParameter("transaction", auditRequest.getTransaction());
        return query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Comment: When you say not getting updated, do you mean the update runs fine but 0 rows are updated?

Comment: Yes Steve. query.executeUpdate(); is returning 0 when I say not getting updated.

Comment: Steve I am inserting a new record when I get request to my service and updates the same record when the service completes it call. Below is the insertion logic.

Comment: public EventTransaction insertTransaction(AuditRequest auditRequest) throws TesException {

        EventTransaction et= new EventTransaction();
        et.setTransUID(auditRequest.getTransUID());
        et.setTransaction(auditRequest.getTransaction());
        et.setStartDateTimestamp(getTimestamp(auditRequest.getStartDateTime()));
        et.setStatus(auditRequest.getStatus());
        et.setSourceType(auditRequest.getSourceType());
        et.setSource(auditRequest.getSource());
        et.setData(auditRequest.getData());
        et= super.create(et);
             return et;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The EntityManager needs to be flushed before you run the query. It looks like most of the time this is happening already, but when the new EventTransaction hasn't been written to the database yet, there's nothing to update. Then your database transaction commits and the EntityManager is flushed as part of the commit process, writing the unaltered EventTransaction to the database.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the quick response.so I need to run flush after the executeUpdate right or You mean before I run the update query. Steve any comment on why it is getting most of the times and not happening in some cases.

Comment: You need to flush before the update query. My guess is that most of the time there's an intervening commit or some other part of your code calls flush.